# Uniqueness proof of the left-inverse of a function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I attempted to prove directly that a function cannot have more than one left inverse, by showing that two left inverses of a function $f$, must be the same function.

*My Proof*

Let $f: A \to B, g: B \to A, h: B \to A$. Suppose $g$ and $h$ are left-inverses of $f$.

Thus $ g \circ f = i_A = h \circ f$. Where $i_A(x) =x$ for all $x \in A$.

Therefore we have $g(f(a)) = h(f(a))$ for $a\in A$. Now since $f$ must be injective for $f$ to have a left-inverse, we have $f(a) = f(a) \implies a = a$ for all $a \in A$ and for all $f(a) \in B$

Put $b = f(a)$. Then $g(b) = h(b) \
 \ \ \forall b \in B$, and thus $g = h$. $\square$

---

However based on the answers I saw here: [Can a function have more than one left inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579460/can-a-function-have-more-than-one-left-inverse), it seems that my proof may be incorrect. But which part of my proof is incorrect, I can't seem to find anything wrong with my proof.

Comment: You need $f$ to be surjective.

Comment: @mfl, that's if $f$ has a right inverse, this is for left inverses

Comment: You can't say $b=f(a)$ for any $b\in B$ unless $f$ is surjective. So, you have that $g=h$ on the range of $f,$ but not necessarily on $B.$

Comment: As @mfl pointed, $f$ must be surjective for the left inverse to be unique. Otherwise, $g$ and $h$ may differ in points that do not belong to $f$'s image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're assuming that whenever you have a $b\in B$ there will be some $a$ such that $b=f(a)$. This is not necessarily the case!

However, if you explicitly add an assumption that $f$ is *surjective*, then a left inverse, if it exists, will be unique.

---

For your comment: There are two *different* things you can conclude from the additional assumption that $f$ is surjective:

- There is *at least one* right inverse.
- There is *at most one* left inverse (and if there is one, it is actually two-sided).

Conversely, if you assume that $f$ is *injective*, you will know that

- There is *at most one* right inverse (and if there is one, it is actually two-sided).
- There is *at least one* left inverse (except in the case drhab points out below).

Comment: Exception on last bullet: $f:\varnothing\to B$ is (vacuously) injective, but if $B\neq\varnothing$ then it has no left inverse.

Comment: @Henning Makholm, by two-sided, do you mean *bijective*?

Comment: @Perturbative: A _two-sided_ inverse to $f$ is a function $g$ such that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are both the identity on their respective domains. (A two sided inverse is necessarily a bijective function).

Answer (score 2):

Do you necessarily have $ \forall b \in B, \exists a \in A, b = f(a) $?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the example

$$A=\{1,2\};B=\{1,2,3\}$$ and $$f:A\to B, g,h:B\to A$$ given by $$f(1)=1; f(2)=2; g(1)=1;g(2)=2;g(3)=1;h(1)=1;h(2)=2;h(3)=2.$$

Note that $h\circ f=g\circ f=id_A.$ However $g\ne h.$ What fails to have equality? That $f$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to specifically point out that the deduction "Now since $f$ must be injective for $f$ to have a left-inverse, we have $f(a)=f(a)\Rightarrow a=a$ for all $a\in A$ and for all $f(a)\in B$" is rather pointless, since $a=a$ for every $a\in A$ anyway. The problem is in the part "Put $b=f(a)$. Then $g(b)=h(b)$   $\forall b\in B$, and thus $g=h$." This is where you implicitly assumed that the range of $f$ contains $B$.

The claim "a function cannot have more than one left inverse" itself can be false or true, depending on what you mean by a "function" and "left inverse". In the "category convention" it is false, as explained in previous answers, and in the "graph convention" it is true, if one interprets "left inverse" in a proper fashion.

Adopt the "graph convention" in which a function $f$ is a rule which assigns a unique value $f(x)$ into each $x$ in its domain $\mathrm{dom}(f)$. In this convention two functions $f$ and $g$ are the same if and only if $\mathrm{dom}(f)=\mathrm{dom}(g)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for every $x$ in their common domain. Denote $\mathrm{ran}(f):=\{ f(x): x\in \mathrm{dom}(f)\}$. The statement "$f:A\to B$ is a function" is interpreted as "$f$ is a function with $\mathrm{dom}(f)=A$ and $\mathrm{ran}(f)\subset B$" and the statement "$f:A\to B$ is a surjection" as "$f:A\to B$ is a function with $\mathrm{ran}(f)=B$." The statement "$f$ is a surjection" is meaningless in this convention.

Let us say that "$g$ is a left inverse of $f$" if $\mathrm{dom}(g)=\mathrm{ran}(f)$ and $g(f(x))=x$ for every $x\in\mathrm{dom}(f)$. Then it is trivial that if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are left inverses of $f$, then $g_1=g_2$. In fact, in this convention $f$ is an injection if and only if $f$ has a left inverse $g$, and if this is the case, $g$ is the inverse function of $f:\mathrm{dom}(f)\to\mathrm{ran}(f)$.